# Force.com User Subscription Limitations, need a workaround for using opportunity

Tags: force.com, opportunity, chatter-feed-tracking, userlicense, userrecordaccess

In our organization, we are planning to take Licenses for few users with very limited accessibility , where they can edit accounts, contacts and Opportunities and few custom objects.

We are thinking for taking Force.com License where i can get Accounts and Contacts but i need Opportunities(Chatter Tracking also) as well. is their any workaround for this requirement. Or else is there any licence type which maps this requirement under $25.

Please provide few suggestions.

Thanks,
Sujan

Answer (score 0):

- Best shot: Just buy the Salescloud licence.
- Second best: Create a custom Opportunity object and all the CRM features you need